# What is the default browser of Android 5.0 and above?

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, browser, chrome-for-android

Android devices used to have its stock web browser as its default browser, but nowadays, it is replaced by Chrome. And it is said that the default browser of Android 5.0 and above is going to be Chrome. Having said that, what happens if a phone with stock web browser is updated to Android 5.0? Is its stock web browser is deleted as well as replaced by Chrome? Or does it stay as its stock web browser even after the update?
If there is any web-site that could support your answer, please attatch its URL as well.

Thanks.

Comment: I would say, it's really depend on who provides the update. Nexus devices are controlled by Google, and they have used Chrome since JellyBean (or even before). If you're flashing custom ROM based on Lollipop, its developer may choose not to include Chrome and use other browser instead.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. What about those sold by cellphone carriers? Are their default browsers also depending on manufacturers? Is there any phones whose browser is the stock browser even after being updated to Android 5.0?

Answer (score 4):

Lollipop has chrome as its default browser. Even devices which had native browser on KitKat deletes the native browser upon lollipop update.

Answer (score 3):

Depends on the provider of the ROM. Currently Nexus & Moto devices having lollipop, has Chrome as default browser because both are having pure android.

If you are having phone from other manufacturers, it really depends on them what will they provide.

If you are using custom ROM then its up-to the developer which to set as default browser.